# SwiftUI List Button with Disclosure Indicator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a SwiftUI view that consists of a list with some items. Some of these are links to other screens (so I use `NavigationLink` to do this) and others are actions I want to perform on the current screen (E.g. button to show action sheet).

I am looking for a way for a `Button` in a SwiftUI `List` to show with a disclosure indicator (the chevron at the right hand sign that is shown for `NavigationLink`).

Is this possible?

E.g.

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State private var showingActionSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Navigation Link", destination: Text("xx"))
                Button("Action Sheet") {
                    self.showingActionSheet = true
                }
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingActionSheet) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Title"), buttons: [
                    .default(Text("Do Something")) {  },
                    .cancel()
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current Behaviour:

[image: Current Behaviour]

Wanted Behaviour:

[image: Wanted Behaviour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer uses the [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) framework, used to:

> Introspect underlying UIKit components from SwiftUI

In this case, it is used to deselect the row after the `NavigationLink` is pressed.

I would think a button with the normal accent color and without the NavigationLink be more intuitive to a user, but if this is what you need, here it is. The following answer should work for you:

```
import Introspect
import SwiftUI


struct ExampleView: View {
    
    @State private var showingActionSheet = false
    @State private var tableView: UITableView?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Navigation Link", destination: Text("xx"))
                
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: EmptyView(),
                    isActive: Binding<Bool>(
                        get: { false },
                        set: { _ in
                            showingActionSheet = true
                            
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                deselectRows()
                            }
                        }
                    )
                ) {
                    Text("Action Sheet")
                }
            }
            .introspectTableView { tableView = $0 }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingActionSheet) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Title"), buttons: [
                    .default(Text("Do Something")) {  },
                    .cancel()
                ])
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func deselectRows() {
        if let tableView = tableView, let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            tableView.deselectRow(at: selectedRow, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is how I implemented inside a **Section** in the **List** view. I guess Its similar to what @George has suggested above. `HStack { Button { showPopover.toggle() } label: { NavigationLink(destination: {}, label: { Text("Version Number") Spacer() Text("1.1.0") })`.

Answer (score 2):

The possible approach is to make row with custom chevron, like in demo below (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

[image: demo]

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State private var showingActionSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    Text("Navigation Link")

                    // need to hide navigation link to use same chevrons
                    // because default one is different
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text("xx")) { EmptyView() }
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
                HStack {
                    Button("Action Sheet") {
                        self.showingActionSheet = true
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Spacer()
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingActionSheet) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Title"), buttons: [
                    .default(Text("Do Something")) {  },
                    .cancel()
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a ZStack to put a `NavigationLink` with an empty label behind the actual label content. This way you get the correct chevron symbol.
For the `isActive` Binding, you can just use a `.constant(false)` Binding that will always return false and cannot be changed.

This will result in a row that looks exactly like a NavigationLink, but behaves like a Button. This unfortunately also includes the drawback that the user has to click on the label-content (the text) to activate the button and cannot just click on empty space of the cell.

[image: Screenshot]

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State private var showingActionSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink("Navigation Link", destination: Text("xx"))
                Button {
                    self.showingActionSheet = true
                } label: {
                    // Put a NavigationLink behind the actual label for the chevron
                    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        // NavigationLink that can never be activated
                        NavigationLink(
                            isActive: .constant(false),
                            destination: { EmptyView() },
                            label: { EmptyView() }
                        )
                        // Actual label content
                        Text("Action Sheet")
                    }
                }
                // Prevent the blue button tint
                .buttonStyle(.plain)
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingActionSheet) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text("Title"), buttons: [
                    .default(Text("Do Something")) {  },
                    .cancel()
                ])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct NavigationButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            NavigationLink(
                isActive: .constant(false),
                destination: { EmptyView() },
                label: { EmptyView() }
            )
            configuration.label
        }
    }
}
```

> Example:

```
NavigationView {
            List {
                
                Button(action: {
                    openURL(URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!)
                }) {
                    Text("Visit Apple")
                }
                .buttonStyle(NavigationButton())
                
            }
}
```